# Silverlight RichTextBox Anchoring of Content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I'm trying to find out how to anchor all of the content in a RichTextBox control to a particular location, for example: horizontal = center and vertical = center. I can horizontally align paragraphs, but not all of the content in the control itself (which anchors at top/left by default). It appears, from the documentation that `<VerticalContentAlignment>` and `<HorizonalContentAlignment>` should be able to be used for this effect, but setting doesn't do anything to the content in the control.

Does anyone know if:

- It is just plain impossible to anchor
  all content in a RichTextBox?
- `<VerticalContentAlignment>` and
  `<HorizonalContentAlignment>` do
  indeed work, but I'm just not using
  them correctly and need to do
  something else?

Other controls do have this feature, for example the below works fine:

```
<Button  Width="73" Height="76" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">hello</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Create a copy of the style and then in the ScrollViewer section, put this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```